# Assert identity of functor applications across interfaces

Tags: types, interface, module, ocaml

Suppose two simple OCaml interfaces:

```
module type FOO = sig
    open Batteries
    module StrMap : Map.S with type key = string

    val foo : int StrMap.t -> int
end

module type BAR = sig
    open Batteries
    module StrMap : Map.S with type key = string

    val bar : unit -> int StrMap.t
end
```

and their trivial implementations:

```
module Foo : FOO = struct module StrMap = Map.Make(String) let foo map = 0 end ;;
module Bar : BAR = struct module StrMap = Map.Make(String) let bar () = StrMap.empty end
```

The following statement yields a compiler error:

```
utop # Foo.foo (Bar.bar ()) ;;
Error: This expression has type int Bar.StrMap.t but an expression was expected of type int Foo.StrMap.t
```

Obviously, OCaml does not unify beyond module definitions. Hence both map-types are considered non-equal. 
Of course, I could move the `StrMap` definition into another module, but this is hardly compositional. I am pretty sure their must be a simpler solution to this.

How do I express a requirement to a type defined by a functor inside a module interface without refering to a concrete module that is the result of said functor?

Comment: Do you really need to have that same module constructed in both `Foo` and `Bar`? Do you want to avoid either of them to depend on an external module?

Answer (score 2):

Well, both module signature give a module of signature `Map.S with type key = string`. But it is nowhere stated that it is the same.

You should ad that information somewhere visible out of the modules.

For instance, your module definitions could add a with clause:

```
module Foo : FOO with module StrMap = Map.Make(String) = struct module StrMap = Map.Make(String) let foo map = 0 end
module Bar : BAR with module StrMap = Map.Make(String) = struct module StrMap = Map.Make(String) let bar () = StrMap.empty end
```

Of course, this makes your module StrMap fully visible on the outside, but you can avoid that by restricting it in your mli file:

```
(* mli code*)
module Foo : FOO 
module Bar : BAR with module StrMap = Foo.StrMap (* so that both modules can still be used together *)
```

You can also ensure the types are the same without showing module equality by replacing the `with module StrMap = ...` by `with type t = ...`.

For more on the with operator, see [here](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/modtypes.html#sec193) for the regular `with` and [here](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/extn.html#sec234) for `with :=`